# Can't insert an element without overwriting existing ones

Tags: php, elasticsearch

Trying to insert an element to existing index via the [Elasticsearch-PHP](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/index.html), however it overwrites existing element in that index. I'm using the `index(..)` method:

```
$params = [
            'index' => 'my-index',
            'type' => '_doc',
            'id' => $request['site_id']
        ];

$params['body'] = [
                'partnerId' => $request['site_id'],
                'lang' => $request['lang'],
                'info' => $request['info'],
                'options' => $request['options']
            ]

$client = ClientBuilder::create()->build();
$client->index($params);
```

How to make a `PUT` request with the elasticSearch PHP client?

**Updated** to give more information about the problem I'm having. Here is what I had in elasticsearch before the `index(..)` method call:

```
{
  "took": 0,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 3,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 1.0,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "partner-settings",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1ru",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "partnerId": 1,
          "lang": "ru",
          "loggedInMenu": {
            "pathPrefix": "/user",
            "sections": [
              {
                "title": "Баланс",
                "path": "/balance",
                "icon": "icon-balance"
              },
              {
                "title": "Уведомления",
                "path": "/notifications",
                "icon": "icon-notifications-bell"
              },
              {
                "title": "Бонусы",
                "path": "/bonuses",
                "icon": "icon-bonus"
              },
              {
                "title": "Личные Данные",
                "path": "/personal-details",
                "icon": "icon-profile"
              },
              {
                "title": "Верификация",
                "path": "/verification",
                "icon": "icon-docs"
              },
              {
                "title": "Снять со Счета",
                "path": "/withdraw",
                "icon": "icon-withdraw"
              },
              {
                "title": "История",
                "path": "/transaction-history",
                "icon": "icon-history"
              },
              {
                "title": "Лимиты",
                "path": "/limits",
                "icon": "icon-limit"
              },
              {
                "title": "Выйти",
                "logout": true,
                "icon": "icon-profile-logout"
              }
            ]
          },
          "validators": {
            "email-min-6": {
              "message": "Email should be at least 6 characters long",
              "rgx": "%5E.+%24"
            },
            "phone-number": {
              "message": "Please provide a valid phone number (6+ chars)",
              "rgx": "%5E%5B+%5D+%5B0-9%5D%7B1%2C%7D%5Cs%3F%5C%28%3F%5B0-9%5D%7B1%2C%7D%5C%29%3F%5Cs%3F%5B-%5Cs%5C0-9%5D%7B4%2C%7D%24"
            },
            "username-min-4": {
              "message": "Username should have length of at least 6 characters",
              "rgx": "%5E%5BA-Za-z0-9_-%5D%7B4%2C%7D%24"
            },
            "username-min-6": {
              "message": "Username should have length of at least 6 characters",
              "rgx": "%5E%5BA-Za-z0-9_-%5D%7B6%2C%7D%24"
            },
            "password-min-6": {
              "message": "Password should have length of at least 6 characters",
              "rgx": "%5BA-Za-z0-9%5D%7B6%2C%7D"
            },
            "email-rfc": {
              "message": "Email format is incorrect",
              "rgx": "(%3F%3A%5Ba-z0-9!%23%24%25%26'*%2B%2F%3D%3F%5E_%60%7B%7C%7D~-%5D%2B(%3F%3A%5C%5C.%5Ba-z0-9!%23%24%25%26'*%2B%2F%3D%3F%5E_%60%7B%7C%7D~-%5D%2B)*%7C%5C%22(%3F%3A%5B%5Cx01-%5Cx08%5Cx0b%5Cx0c%5Cx0e-%5Cx1f%5Cx21%5Cx23-%5Cx5b%5Cx5d-%5Cx7f%5D%7C%5C%5C%5B%5Cx01-%5Cx09%5Cx0b%5Cx0c%5Cx0e-%5Cx7f%5D)*%5C%22)%40(%3F%3A(%3F%3A%5Ba-z0-9%5D(%3F%3A%5Ba-z0-9-%5D*%5Ba-z0-9%5D)%3F%5C.)%2B%5Ba-z0-9%5D(%3F%3A%5Ba-z0-9-%5D*%5Ba-z0-9%5D)%3F%7C%5C%5B(%3F%3A(%3F%3A25%5B0-5%5D%7C2%5B0-4%5D%5B0-9%5D%7C%5B01%5D%3F%5B0-9%5D%5B0-9%5D%3F)%5C.)%7B3%7D(%3F%3A25%5B0-5%5D%7C2%5B0-4%5D%5B0-9%5D%7C%5B01%5D%3F%5B0-9%5D%5B0-9%5D%3F%7C%5Ba-z0-9-%5D*%5Ba-z0-9%5D%3A(%3F%3A%5B%5Cx01-%5Cx08%5Cx0b%5Cx0c%5Cx0e-%5Cx1f%5Cx21-%5Cx5a%5Cx53-%5Cx7f%5D%7C%5C%5C%5B%5Cx01-%5Cx09%5Cx0b%5Cx0c%5Cx0e-%5Cx7f%5D)%2B)%5C%5D)"
            },
            "first-name-min-3": {
              "message": "First name should contain at least 3 alphabetical characters",
              "rgx": "%5E%5BA-Za-z%5Cs%5D%7B3%2C%7D%24"
            },
            "last-name-min-3": {
              "message": "Last name should contain at least 3 alphabetical characters",
              "rgx": "%5E%5BA-Za-z%5Cs%5D%7B3%2C%7D%24"
            },
            "zip-code-min-4": {
              "message": "Zip code should be at least 4 characters long",
              "rgx": "%5E%5BA-Za-z0-9%5Cs%5D%7B4%2C%7D%24"
            }
          },
          "bonus": [

          ],
          "payments": [

          ],
          "metaTags": [

          ],
          "paymentIcons": [

          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "partner-settings",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1en",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "partnerId": 1,
          "lang": "en",
          "loggedInMenu": {
            "pathPrefix": "/user",
            "sections": [
              {
                "title": "My Balance",
                "path": "/balance",
                "icon": "icon-balance"
              },
              {
                "title": "Notifications",
                "path": "/notifications",
                "icon": "icon-notifications-bell"
              },
              {
                "title": "Bonuses",
                "path": "/bonuses",
                "icon": "icon-bonus"
              },
              {
                "title": "Personal Details",
                "path": "/personal-details",
                "icon": "icon-profile"
              },
              {
                "title": "Verification",
                "path": "/verification",
                "icon": "icon-docs"
              },
              {
                "title": "Withdraw",
                "path": "/withdraw",
                "icon": "icon-withdraw"
              },
              {
                "title": "History",
                "path": "/transaction-history",
                "icon": "icon-history"
              },
              {
                "title": "Limits",
                "path": "/limits",
                "icon": "icon-limit"
              },
              {
                "title": "Logout",
                "logout": true,
                "icon": "icon-profile-logout"
              }
            ]
          },          
          "validators": {
            "email-min-6": {
              "message": "Email should be at least 6 characters long",
              "rgx": "%5E.+%24"
            },
            "phone-number": {
              "message": "Please provide a valid phone number (6+ chars)",
              "rgx": "%5E%5B+%5D+%5B0-9%5D%7B1%2C%7D%5Cs%3F%5C%28%3F%5B0-9%5D%7B1%2C%7D%5C%29%3F%5Cs%3F%5B-%5Cs%5C0-9%5D%7B4%2C%7D%24"
            },
            "username-min-4": {
              "message": "Username should have length of at least 6 characters",
              "rgx": "%5E%5BA-Za-z0-9_-%5D%7B4%2C%7D%24"
            },
            "username-min-6": {
              "message": "Username should have length of at least 6 characters",
              "rgx": "%5E%5BA-Za-z0-9_-%5D%7B6%2C%7D%24"
            },
            "password-min-6": {
              "message": "Password should have length of at least 6 characters",
              "rgx": "%5BA-Za-z0-9%5D%7B6%2C%7D"
            },
            "email-rfc": {
              "message": "Email format is incorrect",
              "rgx": "(%3F%3A%5Ba-z0-9!%23%24%25%26'*%2B%2F%3D%3F%5E_%60%7B%7C%7D~-%5D%2B(%3F%3A%5C%5C.%5Ba-z0-9!%23%24%25%26'*%2B%2F%3D%3F%5E_%60%7B%7C%7D~-%5D%2B)*%7C%5C%22(%3F%3A%5B%5Cx01-%5Cx08%5Cx0b%5Cx0c%5Cx0e-%5Cx1f%5Cx21%5Cx23-%5Cx5b%5Cx5d-%5Cx7f%5D%7C%5C%5C%5B%5Cx01-%5Cx09%5Cx0b%5Cx0c%5Cx0e-%5Cx7f%5D)*%5C%22)%40(%3F%3A(%3F%3A%5Ba-z0-9%5D(%3F%3A%5Ba-z0-9-%5D*%5Ba-z0-9%5D)%3F%5C.)%2B%5Ba-z0-9%5D(%3F%3A%5Ba-z0-9-%5D*%5Ba-z0-9%5D)%3F%7C%5C%5B(%3F%3A(%3F%3A25%5B0-5%5D%7C2%5B0-4%5D%5B0-9%5D%7C%5B01%5D%3F%5B0-9%5D%5B0-9%5D%3F)%5C.)%7B3%7D(%3F%3A25%5B0-5%5D%7C2%5B0-4%5D%5B0-9%5D%7C%5B01%5D%3F%5B0-9%5D%5B0-9%5D%3F%7C%5Ba-z0-9-%5D*%5Ba-z0-9%5D%3A(%3F%3A%5B%5Cx01-%5Cx08%5Cx0b%5Cx0c%5Cx0e-%5Cx1f%5Cx21-%5Cx5a%5Cx53-%5Cx7f%5D%7C%5C%5C%5B%5Cx01-%5Cx09%5Cx0b%5Cx0c%5Cx0e-%5Cx7f%5D)%2B)%5C%5D)"
            },
            "first-name-min-3": {
              "message": "First name should contain at least 3 alphabetical characters",
              "rgx": "%5E%5BA-Za-z%5Cs%5D%7B3%2C%7D%24"
            },
            "last-name-min-3": {
              "message": "Last name should contain at least 3 alphabetical characters",
              "rgx": "%5E%5BA-Za-z%5Cs%5D%7B3%2C%7D%24"
            },
            "zip-code-min-4": {
              "message": "Zip code should be at least 4 characters long",
              "rgx": "%5E%5BA-Za-z0-9%5Cs%5D%7B4%2C%7D%24"
            }
          },
          "bonus": [

          ],
          "payments": [

          ],
          "metaTags": [

          ],
          "paymentIcons": [

          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "partner-settings",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1am",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "partnerId": 1,
          "lang": "am",
          "loggedInMenu": {
            "pathPrefix": "/user",
            "sections": [
              {
                "title": "Իմ Հաշվեկշիռը",
                "path": "/balance",
                "icon": "icon-balance"
              },
              {
                "title": "Ծանուցումներ",
                "path": "/notifications",
                "icon": "icon-notifications-bell"
              },
              {
                "title": "Բոնուսներ",
                "path": "/bonuses",
                "icon": "icon-bonus"
              },
              {
                "title": "Անձնական Տվյալներ",
                "path": "/personal-details",
                "icon": "icon-profile"
              },
              {
                "title": "Հաստատում",
                "path": "/verification",
                "icon": "icon-docs"
              },
              {
                "title": "Հանել Հաշվից",
                "path": "/withdraw",
                "icon": "icon-withdraw"
              },
              {
                "title": "Պատմություն",
                "path": "/transaction-history",
                "icon": "icon-history"
              },
              {
                "title": "Լիմիտներ",
                "path": "/limits",
                "icon": "icon-limit"
              },
              {
                "title": "Դուրս Գալ",
                "logout": true,
                "icon": "icon-profile-logout"
              }
            ]
          },          
          "validators": {
            "email-min-6": {
              "message": "Email should be at least 6 characters long",
              "rgx": "%5E.+%24"
            },
            "phone-number": {
              "message": "Please provide a valid phone number (6+ chars)",
              "rgx": "%5E%5B+%5D+%5B0-9%5D%7B1%2C%7D%5Cs%3F%5C%28%3F%5B0-9%5D%7B1%2C%7D%5C%29%3F%5Cs%3F%5B-%5Cs%5C0-9%5D%7B4%2C%7D%24"
            },
            "username-min-4": {
              "message": "Username should have length of at least 6 characters",
              "rgx": "%5E%5BA-Za-z0-9_-%5D%7B4%2C%7D%24"
            },
            "username-min-6": {
              "message": "Username should have length of at least 6 characters",
              "rgx": "%5E%5BA-Za-z0-9_-%5D%7B6%2C%7D%24"
            },
            "password-min-6": {
              "message": "Password should have length of at least 6 characters",
              "rgx": "%5BA-Za-z0-9%5D%7B6%2C%7D"
            },
            "email-rfc": {
              "message": "Email format is incorrect",
              "rgx": "(%3F%3A%5Ba-z0-9!%23%24%25%26'*%2B%2F%3D%3F%5E_%60%7B%7C%7D~-%5D%2B(%3F%3A%5C%5C.%5Ba-z0-9!%23%24%25%26'*%2B%2F%3D%3F%5E_%60%7B%7C%7D~-%5D%2B)*%7C%5C%22(%3F%3A%5B%5Cx01-%5Cx08%5Cx0b%5Cx0c%5Cx0e-%5Cx1f%5Cx21%5Cx23-%5Cx5b%5Cx5d-%5Cx7f%5D%7C%5C%5C%5B%5Cx01-%5Cx09%5Cx0b%5Cx0c%5Cx0e-%5Cx7f%5D)*%5C%22)%40(%3F%3A(%3F%3A%5Ba-z0-9%5D(%3F%3A%5Ba-z0-9-%5D*%5Ba-z0-9%5D)%3F%5C.)%2B%5Ba-z0-9%5D(%3F%3A%5Ba-z0-9-%5D*%5Ba-z0-9%5D)%3F%7C%5C%5B(%3F%3A(%3F%3A25%5B0-5%5D%7C2%5B0-4%5D%5B0-9%5D%7C%5B01%5D%3F%5B0-9%5D%5B0-9%5D%3F)%5C.)%7B3%7D(%3F%3A25%5B0-5%5D%7C2%5B0-4%5D%5B0-9%5D%7C%5B01%5D%3F%5B0-9%5D%5B0-9%5D%3F%7C%5Ba-z0-9-%5D*%5Ba-z0-9%5D%3A(%3F%3A%5B%5Cx01-%5Cx08%5Cx0b%5Cx0c%5Cx0e-%5Cx1f%5Cx21-%5Cx5a%5Cx53-%5Cx7f%5D%7C%5C%5C%5B%5Cx01-%5Cx09%5Cx0b%5Cx0c%5Cx0e-%5Cx7f%5D)%2B)%5C%5D)"
            },
            "first-name-min-3": {
              "message": "First name should contain at least 3 alphabetical characters",
              "rgx": "%5E%5BA-Za-z%5Cs%5D%7B3%2C%7D%24"
            },
            "last-name-min-3": {
              "message": "Last name should contain at least 3 alphabetical characters",
              "rgx": "%5E%5BA-Za-z%5Cs%5D%7B3%2C%7D%24"
            },
            "zip-code-min-4": {
              "message": "Zip code should be at least 4 characters long",
              "rgx": "%5E%5BA-Za-z0-9%5Cs%5D%7B4%2C%7D%24"
            }
          },          
          "bonus": [

          ],
          "payments": [

          ],
          "metaTags": [

          ],
          "paymentIcons": [

          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And here is what I have after it:

```
    {
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 3,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 1.0,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "partner-settings",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1en",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "partnerId": "1",
          "lang": "en",
          "info": "Information about site exclusion",
          "options": {
            "60": "60 minutes",
            "1w": "1 week",
            "5y": "5 years"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "partner-settings",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1am",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "partnerId": "1",
          "lang": "am",
          "info": "Information about site exclusion am",
          "options": {
            "60": "60 րոպե",
            "1w": "1 շաբաթ",
            "5y": "5 տարի"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "partner-settings",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1ru",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "partnerId": "1",
          "lang": "ru",
          "info": "Information about site exclusion ru",
          "options": {
            "60": "60 минут",
            "1w": "1 неделя",
            "5y": "5 года"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the value of the `id` you're using, i.e. `$request['site_id']`

If you don't the next document that has the same ID will overwrite the existing document with that id.

**UPDATE:**

Actually, you're problem is that you're not using the right operation. Since you're not reindexing the full document but only a part of it, you should not be using the `index` operation but the [`update` one](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/updating_documents.html). So you can do it like this instead:

```
$params = [
            'index' => 'my-index',
            'type' => '_doc',
            'id' => $request['site_id']
];

$params['body'] = [
        'doc_as_upsert' => true,
        'doc' => [
                'partnerId' => $request['site_id'],
                'lang' => $request['lang'],
                'info' => $request['info'],
                'options' => $request['options']
        ]
]

$client = ClientBuilder::create()->build();
$client->update($params);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually it overrides other documents in the given index having different `id`-s. The `id` isn't the case here.

Comment: How do you now that other documents are overridden?

Comment: Before calling `index(..)` there were other documents also in the `my-index`, after calling it I get only new inserted document in the index.

Comment: Can you list the ids of the documents that are in your index before calling index and then the same after calling index? It's highly unlikely that an index call removes documents. And overriding can only happen if the ids are the same

Comment: You mean get all elements and reinsert them along the new one?

Comment: No, I'm curious why you think that documents are disappearing when indexing new documents. This can only happen 1) if you have another process doing deletes or 2) if you index the new documents with the same ids as the older documents

Comment: I'm getting the list with separate `GET` request (tried also outside the code, with the "postman"); I don't think there is another process doing deletes, and ids are different. It seemed weird to me that `index` method overwrites existing documents so I posted the question. I thought that there is an another way of doing it, but it seems that using `index` should do the job, and the problem is in the something else.

Comment: It's still not clear to me why you think documents are being overridden... The behavior you're describing is not something that the index operation does. So far, there's nothing tangible that backs up your claim. Show some stats (before/after), show more relevant code, provide something that can be reproduced... You need to help us help you.

Comment: As it was urgent at a time, I fixed my problem with workaround of using different indexes. Please see my updated question. Hope it will give you more insight about the issue. Thanks.

Comment: I now see exactly what the problem is. See my updated answer!

Comment: Thanks for the update! I'll give it a try and get back to you.

Comment: now getting "document missing index_uuid" error: `{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"document_missing_exception","reason":"[_doc][3am]: document missing","index_uuid":"joimV6TXQkik4UA4BY7x7A","shard":"0","index":"partner-settings"}],"type":"document_missing_exception","reason":"[_doc][3am]: document missing","index_uuid":"joimV6TXQkik4UA4BY7x7A","shard":"0","index":"partner-settings"},"status":404}`

Comment: Then it means that the document with ID `3am` doesn't exist yet, is that possible?

Comment: If that's the case, you can additionally specify `doc_as_upsert: true` to create the document if it doesn't exist. I've updated my answer, check it out.

Comment: That was exactly what I needed! Missed that part, that solved my problem. +1 and thank you very much!

Comment: Awesome, glad we figured it out!